# How do I stop tables inside a list from expanding the list

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a **List** that contains a **Table**. The List is sized sufficiently that the table should be able to fit 10ish rows, which is more data than should ever come out in that table so that should be fine.

My problem is that as rows are generated in the Table, it causes the List to resize as if it needed to grow to accomodate the rows. I thought that the `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` property was intended to prevent this behaviour however that setting does not make a difference.

Here's an example (cropped to avoid some data appearing); as you can see the left hand List, which is the only one in which the Table contains some data, has expanded vertically even though there is plenty of room for the table within the list.

[image]

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Try using rectangles instead of lists.

Comment: @StevenWhite thanks, but I need to generate the rectangle for multiple data items which requires a list.

Answer (score 0):

Put your list in a second rectangle.  Setup the rectangle to show its border.  That way you have a border with a constant size from the rectangle.

1. Create a rectangle
2. Setup rectangle border to appear
3. Create a list that populates based on your data
4. Drag and drop the list into the rectangle

*Note that I did notice that the rectangle will grow in size if the list has enough elements to expand beyond the rectangle border.  This shouldn't be an issue in your case, but it could impact someone else.*

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work either - the rectangle just automatically grows to accommodate the increased size of the list.

Comment: I just tried it again and it is working for me.  I've added more detailed steps on exactly what I am doing.  Can you give me the steps that you are doing?